# Is there some tool like apt-fast for snapcraft?

Tags: package-management, snap

On Ubuntu, I've been using `apt-fast` (https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast) which is basically `apt`/`apt-get`/`aptitude` behind `aria2`.

1. Is there something like that for snap packages as well? (It seems like my downloads are really slow.)
2. What tool do snap packages (snapcraft) use to download the packages? (I'm guessing something like wget or curl?)

> REASON : At my workplace, I think (best guess) we have a bandwidth
>   limit per thread, but no limit on the number of threads, and something
>   like this would be super useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any built in capabilities or 3rd party applications that provide this capability to Snapcraft directly.

So the typical courses of action for something like this are 1 of the 3 approaches:

1. Setup a caching proxy such as Squid or Artifactory and pull your Snappy repositories through one of these. This will create a local cache of the packages as you use them internally.
2. Mirror the Snapcraft repositories internally on a system, and pull the artifacts from there instead.
3. You may be able to use `parallel` to invoke multiple `snap` commands at the same time to workaround the supposed limitation you're encountering when running one.

Of the 3 options, I typically use 1, and have used 2, for similar situations for other distros packages, not for Snapcraft, but given it's a Canonical product, I don't see why these methods wouldn't work for you as well.

#### Regarding mirroring

It sounds like mirroring is still something that is being worked on according to this thread - [Local mirror for snaps?](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/local-mirror-for-snaps/1903). But one of the developers mentions that Snapcraft just uses standard HTTP(s) to do the downloading, so any old caching proxy would be able to be used here to keep a local cache of the .snap files.